# How to replace a table cell value with a picture?

Tags: javascript, function

I've got a table output that is generated dynamically.

I've got a javascript function that is doing some coloring and replacement of cell values, which is fine (e.g. background becomes green when `innerText==3;` please find the sample code below).

Now I'm trying to insert a picture in those table cells that have `innerText==9`. 
Is it possible to include this functionality in my function?
I tried with a `pictureGrey` declaration an assigned it to `innerText`, but this doesn't work.

Does anyone have an idea, can someone help me?

Thanks a lot in advance, 
Gero B.

```js
    function ModifyData( ) {
      var Elements=document.getElementsByTagName('td');
      pictureGrey="Z_led_grey.gif";

      for(var i=0;i<Elements.length;i++) {
        if(Elements[i].innerText=='3') {
            Elements[i].style.color='green';
            Elements[i].style.background='green';
            Elements[i].innerText=' ';
        }
        if(Elements[i].innerText=='9') {
            Elements[i].innerText= pictureGrey ;
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new image element and append it in the element.  Depending on if the data can subsequently change again you might need to check for the existence of the image first.

**CSS**

```
img.myFullSizeImageClass {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function ModifyData() {
    var Elements = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    pictureGrey = "angular-icon.png";

    for (var i = 0; i < Elements.length; i++) {
        if (Elements[i].firstChild.nodeValue == '3') {
            Elements[i].style.color = 'green';
            Elements[i].style.background = 'green';
            Elements[i].firstChild.nodeValue = ' ';
        }
        else if (Elements[i].firstChild.nodeValue == '9') {
            Elements[i].firstChild.nodeValue = "";
            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.src = pictureGrey;
            img.className = 'myFullSizeImageClass'
            Elements[i].appendChild(img);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi DoctorMick, that comes quite close to what I want. Now it shows the 9 and a placeholder for the image. Is it possible to zoom the image automatically to width and height of the cell (which is dynamic) and to get rid of the number "9"?

Comment: Well, no the picture doesn't show up, a placeholder is displayed, which doesn't fit. Is this link to the picture syntactically correct:   pictureGrey ="C:\temp\Z_led_grau.gif";   ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It works file for me, although with a file in the same directory as the html page.  Does the file definitely exist in that location?

Comment: Just realised the sizing doesn't work.  Easiest way is to create a css style for the image with the width: 100%

Comment: The pictures are small traffic lights with a white surrounding. So I could use a white background color and it should look fine. The images are in that folder, yes, but they don't show up. - I also found out that this function is not working in Firefox, only in MS Internet Explorer. Do you have any idea how to solve that? - Thanks a lot for all your help so far!

Comment: The updated version works on all browsers, innerText isn't supported on FireFox.  The image issue is confusing me, can you right click on the image properties and check the source?  Try pasting that source into a new browser tab and see if it appears, I suspect it won't which implies the path is incorrect (or there are permissions issues perhaps).

Answer (score 0):

please check the below code.

```
function ModifyData( ) {
  var Elements=document.getElementsByTagName('td');
  pictureGrey="Z_led_grey.gif";

  for(var i=0;i<Elements.length;i++) {
    if(Elements[i].innerText=='3') {
        Elements[i].style.color='green';
        Elements[i].style.background='green';
        Elements[i].innerText=' ';
    }
    if(Elements[i].innerText=='9') {
         Elements[i].innerText=' ';
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src=pictureGrey;
        Elements[i].appendChild (img );}
  }
}
```

demo link:
http://jsfiddle.net/asimshahiddIT/acz5xn3b/